# Convert very complex JSON to csv using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataflowtask

I have a very complex JSON format with multiple array's. Need the best solution to convert it to csv file using ADF.

JSON format example:

```
   {
   "elementCollection":[
      {
         "elementId":4643,
         "alias":"f97836a8-7c2e-4aaf-a0c1-551ce93b6ee9",
         "attributes":[
            {
               "Schedule":{
                  "id":"602",
                  "type":"Heading"
               }
            },
            {
               "Release_Name_in_BusinessLine_WS":{
                  "textValue":"xxx",
                  "formattedTextValue":"123",
                  "id":"545",
                  "type":"Text",
                  "xhtmlTextValue":"<div> 21</div>"
               }
            },
            {
               "Type":{
                  "expression":{
                     "valid":"true",
                     "pendingUpdate":"false",
                     "formula":"'Type' + 'EP'"
                  },
                  "textValue":"",
                  "formattedTextValue":"xxx",
                  "id":"544",
                  "type":"Text",
                  "xhtmlTextValue":"<div></div>"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elementId":6443,
         "alias":"f73a8cdd-c4e1-4b21-8253-44c237ea60c2",
         "attributes":[
            {
               "Schedule":{
                  "id":"602",
                  "type":"Heading"
               }
            },
            {
               "Release_Name_in_BusinessLine_WS":{
                  "textValue":"xxx",
                  "formattedTextValue":"123",
                  "id":"545",
                  "type":"Text",
                  "xhtmlTextValue":"<div> 21</div>"
               }
            },
            {
               "Type":{
                  "expression":{
                     "valid":"true",
                     "pendingUpdate":"false",
                     "formula":"'Type' + 'EP'"
                  },
                  "textValue":"",
                  "formattedTextValue":"xxx",
                  "id":"544",
                  "type":"Text",
                  "xhtmlTextValue":"<div></div>"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I did try using aggregate and flattern settings but didn't get desired result as expected. Is there any other way to achieve this, kindly suggest.
I want the output something like below format
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Update:
By using two flatten transformation one for ElementCollection and other for Attributes I am able to see all the objects.But now the problem is with duplicates. For each object inside the attributes two rows are generated (one with null value and other with actual value).

Below is the screenshot how it looks when I do group by only for ReleaseId
[image]

I have around 100 attributes and the total rowcount is 19.The output I get is 19*100 = 1900 rows. so for particular column i need to pick only the actual value. for example if a column has 100 rows only one row will have actual value. Is there any way to aggregate and pick actual values from all the columns.

Thanks in advance !
Is there any way to handle this scenario.

Below is the screnshot of the output I get.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide your next object in the `elementCollection` array and another expected row from the desired output? your JSON looks very complex so need this additional data for better understanding.

Comment: I have added the next object

Answer (score 0):

As your JSON consists multiple objects inside the same array, Dataflow is only identifying the first object columns while using the transformations.

To achieve your requirement, you need to manually create the required columns in the dataflow and **this approach only works for the above case only**.

First flatten the `elementCollection` like below and get the `elementId` and `attributes` array columns output.

[image]

It will give the output like this.

[image]

Now, use a **Derived column transformation** and here, create the required column with below expressions.

```
Schedule_id - split(split(toString(attributes),'{"id":"')[2],'"')[1]

Schedule_type - split(split(toString(attributes),'"type":"')[2],'"')[1]

Release_Name_in_BusinessLine_WS_textValue - split(split(toString(attributes),'"textValue":"')[2],'"')[1]

Release_Name_in_BusinessLine_WS_formattedTextValue - split(split(toString(attributes),'"formattedTextValue":"')[2],'"')[1]

Type_formattedTextValue - split(split(toString(attributes),'"formattedTextValue":"')[3],'"')[1]
```

[image]

It will give the output like below.

[image]

Remove the unwanted column `attributes` column using **select transformation**.

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

Add your sink dataset to this dataflow and generate the csv file.

**NOTE:** All the data types of the columns will be string type only because they got generated from `split()`. So, convert those to respective data types before the sink.

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately,this solution doesn't work for me. The JSON snippet what I pasted is just an example, I have 100 attributes inside my elementCollection for each elemenId, and the order of attributes is not same. Example, first elementID will have order as Schedule, Release_Name_in_BusinessLine_WS and Type. Second will have in following order like Release_Name_in_BusinessLine_WS, Type and Schedule. So, Split based on Array doesn't help me. Kindly suggest if you have any other idea. Thanks again for your suggestion!

Comment: also, do we have any option to order the attributes to desired format and achieve this ?

Comment: I think, dataflow might not work for this kind of JSONs. My suggestion is to build your own logic using any programming language like python or pyspark in databricks.

Comment: I am able to flatten the data for all attributes but now the problem is with duplicates.For each object inside the attributes two rows are generated (one with null value and other with actual value).  I have around 100 attributes and the total rowcount is 19. So , the output I get is 19*100 = 1900 rows. Just one row will have actual value and the rest 99 rows will have null values for that elementid.
Is there any way to handle this scenario.